# Looking for a way to identify "proprietary terms" within OpenAI

Tags: openai-api

I am developing a chat system within our company that interacts with OpenAI's ChatGPT. Some of our users express dissatisfaction when they do not receive the expected answers using internal terms that are not generally used in public. For these users, I plan to implement the grounding using the EmbeddedAPI+VectorDatabase, and I am looking for hints on how to create a dictionary for internal terms.

I'm not sure what terms are considered "internal terms" or "proprietary terms", and I'm hoping to get some clues from the chat system's conversation logs.

Is there a method to automatically identify these "internal" or "proprietary" terms?

Thank you.